# filter return true or false

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm using filter to find id in data.it return object not true or false.

How can I return true or false if `val.recoredId === valueId` ?

```
var hasMatch = data.filter(function (val) {
  return (val.recordId === valueId);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for, but assuming `data` is an array, try the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

Comment: You question is really unclear, please read about "how to ask a good question" and try again...

Comment: Is your question "I need to set hasMatch to true if any of the objects in my array have an id equal to valueId"?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I need to set hasMatch to true  not to json object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use find

```
 hasMatch = data.find(function (value) {return value.recordId == valueId });
```

Comment: it still returns a object, wrapping it into a boolean function will return boolean value `hasMatch = Boolean(data.find(a=>{return a.recordId == valueId}))`

Answer (score 27):

Just check the length of filtered results.

```
var hasMatch = data.filter(function (val) {
  return (val.recordId === valueId);
}).length > 0;
```

Comment: @Tushar sure, it will work without that as well since 0 is a falsey value. But maybe for readability and since OP seems to be new to this filter method, I would keep it. Also, then my answer will become identical to yours :)

Comment: Depends whether hasMatch needs to be an actual boolean value - if so then keep the > 0 test.

Answer (score 15):

While calling filter with length appended does resolve this, I would point you to the `some()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
hasMatch = data.some(function (value) {
   return value.recordId == valueId
});
```

This will return a boolean if the array contains any matching `value.recordId == valueId` entries

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var hasMatch = data.filter(function (val) {
    return !!(val.recordId === valueId);                               
});
```

Comment: The `===` operator already returns true or false, so adding `!!` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The question is how to make the `hasMatch` variable a boolean value. Currently it's an array.