# MongoDB: How to filter true / false result returning from $ne/ $eq operator in a single query?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, arraylist

Here  [Possible duplicaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141425/filter-return-true-or-false) but not much useful.

I have a collection like this

```
    {
       "_id": {
           "$oid": "589764fb40948e196cc90e8a"
       },
       "color": "red",
       "tweets": ["I am fine", "I am ok"],
       "userId": "172884537",
       "tweetIds": ["819223623735119873", "819219362049572864"]
   } {
       "_id": {
           "$oid": "589764fb40948e196cc90e8b"
       },
       "color": "red",
       "tweets": ["How are you?", "Where are you"],
       "userId": "4558206579",
       "tweetIds": ["822916538596462592"]
   } {
       "_id": {
           "$oid": "589764fb40948e196cc90e8c"
       },
       "color": "blue",
       "tweets": ["Whats up?", "Good night"],
       "userId": "1893540588",
       "tweetIds": ["822947258186403840", "822498809808728064"]
   } {
       "_id": {
           "$oid": "589764fb40948e196cc90e8d"
       },
       "color": "red",
       "tweets": ["trump"],
       "userId": "781950015858176001",
       "tweetIds": ["819486328467374081", "819220448282079233"]
   }
```

I want to get those userId where the number of tweets and the number of tweetsIds are not equal.

I tried in two way

```
    db.us_election_nodes_with_tweets.aggregate([{
     "$project": {
         "_id": 1,
         "alloc": {
             "$ne": [{
                 "$size": "$tweets"
             }, {
                 "$size": "$tweetIds"
             }]
         }
     }
 }, {
     "$match": {
         "alloc": 1
     }
 }])
```

And the other

```
db.us_election_nodes_with_tweet.find({
    $and: [{
        result: {
            "$ne": [{
                $size: "$tweets"
            }, {
                $size: "$tweetIds"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        result: {
            $exists: true
        }
    }]
}).pretty()
```

If I do this

```
    db.us_election_nodes_with_tweet.aggregate([{
     $project: {
         _id: 0,
         userId: 1,
         result: {
             "$ne": [{
                 $size: "$tweets"
             }, {
                 $size: "$tweetIds"
             }]
         }
     }
 }])
```

I get an output like this. Because $ne returns true it doesn't match and return false where it's matches.

```
{ "userId" : "172884537", "result" : false }
{ "userId" : "781950015858176001", "result" : true}
{ "userId" : "4558206579", "result" : true }
{ "userId" : "1893540588", "result" : false }
```

But here I don't know how to filter only Boolean true from this result. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `$match` to check for `true`.

```
db.us_election_nodes_with_tweets.aggregate([ { "$project": { "_id": 1, "userId":1, "alloc": { "$ne": [ { "$size": "$tweets" }, { "$size": "$tweetIds" } ] } }}, { "$match": { "alloc": true } } ])
```

As an alternative, you can use `$redact` which will `$$PRUNE` when the array size matches else `$$KEEP` the row .

```
db.us_election_nodes_with_tweet.aggregate([{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
                 "$eq": [ { "$size": "$tweets" }, { "$size": "$tweetIds" } ]
            },
            "$$PRUNE",
            "$$KEEP"
        ]
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working in the data format I gave here.  I have big database and I think I have problem in my data format that's why  I got an error. I have find it. 
the error I got 
command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String",
"code" : 17124
egate failed

I have to check my data set.... Thanks .